Concatenate String, and Sheet and Cell Reference
I am trying to create a referenced formula in VBA with combined strings, cell, and sheet references.
I am trying to create a code in VBA that will add the following formula to a cell
= " Sample: " & 'Test 1 - 520 psf'!B5

I am using the following code
Dim Consol_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Consol_Sheet = Sheets("Test 1 - 520 psf")
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:J3").FormulaR1C1 = "= ""Sample: '"" & Consol_Sheet.Name & ""'!"" & R[2]C"

but it does not work. I get the error #name in the cell, and the formula shows this
= "Sample: '" &@ Consol_Sheet.Name & "'!" & B5



' is used to surround sheet name
There is a & in the formula and it is also used as an operator to concate string. Pls don't mix it up.

Pls try
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:J3").FormulaR1C1 = "= ""Sample: ""&'" & Consol_Sheet.Name & "'!R[2]C"

